# Finding cyclic quadrilaterals after drawing orthic triangle of a triangle

Tags: geometry

> [image]
> Find the six cyclic quadrilateral's in the figure
>
> Source: Euclidean Geometry in mathematical Olympiads,page-7

I found three already : AEFH,BFHD, EHCD by the property the if opposite angle of a quadrilateral add up to 180 it's then it's inside a circle. I did some angle chasing and got:

$$<ECD=<DHB=<BFD=<AHE=<AFE$$

Explanation: First quality , exterior angle property of quadrilateral

Second equality and fourth, angles standing on the same chord

Third equality , vertically opposite angles

not quite sure how to proceed further, some hints would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: $3$ more - for example, one is $ABDE$, similarly two more on other two sides of the $\triangle ABC$

Comment: Thank you , I see it now with help of Luca's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circle of diameter BC passes through E and F because the angles BEC and BFC are right angles.

Doing the same for AB and CA finds the remaining cycllic quadrilaterals.